# Asynchonous issue with loop in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to iterate threw a list of item and do some actions on them by calling an API like this example :

```
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
    if (arr[i].id == 42) {
      api.requestAction(arr[i].id, function(error, response){ });
    }
 }
```

Problem is the loop obviously ended before all the requests are done and the program exits. What should I do to manage it ? I saw the "Promise" method but don't really know how I can use it in this case or maybe there's an other solution.

Thank you by advance !

Comment: Are you using any `Promise` library?

Comment: No I'm not using it because I don't really know how to process with it.

Comment: @shaharyar from OP:  *I saw the "Promise" method but not really know how I can use it in this case or maybe there's an other solution*

Comment: Will you be OK if I answer with Promise? Because eventually you'll need to use it. You can't survive on callbacks totally.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cokewocotu/edit?js,console this example uses promises and a loop to do some stuff.

Comment: @Derek By asking I meant he may be using `bluebird` or something but don't know how to loop it.

Comment: If you could modify my code so it works with Promise it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). It's an asyncronous control flow library which provides control flows for things like sequential loops, looping in parralel, and many other common flow control mechanism, check it out.

See code below, the code assumes that you're variable 'arr' is defined somewhere in scope.

npm install async

```
     var async = require("async");




     //Loop through each item, waiting for your
     //asyncronous function to finish before continuing
     //to move onto the next item in the array
     //NOTE: This does not loop sequentially, if you want that function with asyncjs then user eachSeries
     async.each(arr, 

         //Item is the current item being iterated over,
         //callback is the callback you call to finish the current iteration, it accepts an error and result parameter callback(error, result);
         function (item, callback) {
              api.requestAction(item.id, function(error, response){ 

                   //Check for any errors...     
                   if (error) return callback(error);
                   callback(null);
              });
         },
         function (err, result) {
              //You've now finished the loop

              if (err) {
                 //Do something, you passed an error object to
                 //in one of the loop's iterations
              }

              //No errors, move on with your code..
         });
```

Comment: why do you wrap it in a closure?

Comment: Force of habit, just removed the encasing closure :) I do generally wrap any snippets in closure so I can copy and paste assured the code won't break anything else in the destination script. Good call for the readability of the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

With [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) (a promisify http api) you can together with async/await halt the for loop until it's done but this requires node v6+ with `--harmony-async-await` flag added

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function foo() {
  for (let item of arr) {
    if (item.id == 42) {
      let res = await fetch(url)
      let body = await res.text()
      console.log(body)
    }
  }
  console.log('done (after request)')
}
```

now every time you add the async keyword in front of a function it will always return a promise that resolve/rejects when everything is done

```
foo().then(done, fail)
```

---

alternetive you can just wrap you api fn in a promise if you don't want to install node-fetch

```
await new Promise((rs, rj) => {
  api.requestAction(arr[i].id, function(error, response){
    error ? rj(error) : rs(response)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Install [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)

```
npm install bluebird --save
```

**Code**

```
//require npm
var Promise = require("bluebird");

//code
//"promisify" converts traditional callback function into a Promise based function
var _requestAction = Promise.promisify(api.requestAction);

//loop over array
Promise.map(arr, function (value) {
    if (value.id == 42) {
        //async request
        return _requestAction(value.id).then(function (_result) {
            //success
            console.log(_result);
        }).catch(function (e) {
            //error
            console.error(e);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: var _requestAction = Promise.promisify(api.requestAction); here api.requestAction is a function call right.

Comment: No, it is to convert it into `Promise`. I've added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bluebird Promises:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.map(arrayOfIds, function(item){
  return api.requestAction(item);
})
.then(function(response){
 // all the requests are resolved here
})
```

if u want sequential execution of the ids then use `Promise.mapSeries` (is slow as it waits for task to finish)

Comment: ya your solution makes sense, i didn't see he was stopping the loop, thanks for mentioning